# Minimal Discriminant of the Frey Curve

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

According to Frey's work, the minimal discriminant of the Frey equation

$$y^2 = x(x - a^p)(x + b^p)$$

for a nontrivial solution $(a, b, c) \in \mathbb Z^3$ to the Fermat equation $a^p + b^p + c^p = 0$ and $p \geq 5$ prime is

$$\Delta = \frac{(abc)^{2p}}{2^8}$$

I fail to see why this discriminant is minimal. For example, we are assuming throughout all this that $b$ is even and $a$ and $c$ are odd, so what if $p = 11$? Then the valuation of the $\Delta$ at the prime divisor $2$ is at the very least $14 > 12$, and according to Silverman's book, the valuation at every prime divisor of the minimal discriminant must be less than $12$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If $\mathrm{val}_p(\Delta) < 12$, then the discriminant is minimal at $p$. The converse is not true.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true that the valuation of every prime divisor of the minimal discriminant has to be less than $12$. By way of example (there are many simpler), the elliptic curve defined by
$$
y^2 + xy = x^3 − 424151762667003358518x
− 6292273164116612928531204122716
$$
has minimal discriminant divisible by, for example, $2^{33}$, $7^{18}$  and $13^{27}$.

Comment: So why is this equation minimal? I see the equation has integer coefficients. I also calculate the quantity c_4 for this curve to be c^2p - (ab)^p. For this curve to be minimal, it must be the case that no prime with a power larger than 3 attached to it divides c_4, by a theorem from Silverman's AEC book (since the curve fails the discriminant test for minimality and the curve is defined over a field not of char 2 or 3, namely Q). I do not see why this is the case, though.